# Router can't send a file bigger than 8 Mb to printer

Tags: printer, print-server

*I had asked this question yesterday, but I lost access to my account and I don't have enough rep to comment there, so I am asking again.*

I have connected my Epson wired printer to my ISP router by Huawei via USB. Everything works fine except for one big problem. If I try to print a document/image that is any bigger than 8MB after spooling, it fails. So even a 2MB image can’t be printed (As the size increases after spooling).

I don’t know if it is my printer’s problem or the router’s. I am thinking it’s a router issue since the printer doesn’t receive anything to start with. I tried from multiple computers and the same result (although they were all using the same drivers, that could be the issue). The print queue just shows a generic ‘Error’. Event viewer also doesn’t show anything useful.

Are there any alternative drivers I can use to isolate the issue? Is there a way to get more details on the error?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What model is the router?

Comment: @harrymc the model seems to be specific to my ISP but it seems like it is some version of a Huawei HG8245H

Comment: It could be a memory issue [RAM, HW buffer, or cache], albeit I've only ever seen such an issue when transferring files between a router's share and another device, not from one LAN device to another _(the router is simply transferring the data from your device to your printer, much the same as it would be for downloading a file over WAN)_, unless your router is configured as a print server. The most efficient way to troubleshoot is to reach out to your ISP's tech support since it's their router.

Comment: the datasheet for that device doesn't list print sharing via samba. Can you affirm that you can actually print *something* and also that you enabled the right feature (and tell us what the GUI calls it)? ( https://www.router-switch.com/media/upload/product-pdf/huawei-ont-product-datatsheet.pdf ) (the Huawei HG8045Q in that linked doc *does* list samba,; the one mentioned above only lists FTP file storage via usb)

Comment: @Yorik Yes, I can print anything as long as it’s smaller than 8 mb. My model number may be incorrect since I searched it myself online as the  model number on my own router is specific to my ISP. The option is called ‘Home Sharing’. I can link a YouTube video for the gui if you wish.

Comment: can you tell us also what port type the printer is set to on the client machine? You may need to set the printer up as a local device and then point the port via //server/printer_name or try LPR/RAW port type

Comment: @Yorik I have used an Internet port (http://192.168.....) , samba (\\server....) , and a TCP/IP (LPR) port to connect to the printer.  The Internet port and samba worked (as long as the file is smaller than 8mb obviously) but the TCP/IP method did not work.

Comment: @JW0914 But the router _is_ configured as a print server, right? The router is sending print jobs to the printer, so it's a print server, or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: @SameMan2 It is - I misread the second sentence =]

Answer (score 0):

There is no information about any limits in the
[Huawei HG8245H manual](https://setuprouter.com/router/huawei/hg8245h/manuals.htm),
so we have to guess.

I would guess that this relates to some internal limit of
the router,
perhaps the size of the available memory cache (as the file is
received by the router much faster than the printer can receive it,
it needs to be cached).

Your first call should be to complain to your ISP Support and ask
if there is some parameter that can be tweaked to remove this
limitation.

If Support is not helpful,
I would suggest to connect the printer to one computer that is usually
turned on, and to share it on the network from that computer.

For more information see
[How to Share a Printer in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/101147-share-printer-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Yeah the problem seems to be with the router. ISP won’t provide support as “it’s not an endorsed feature” (or maybe they themselves are clueless).

Comment: I find this problem very strange since what I am doing is not a fringe case by any means, so it’s not like no one thought about this and it’s a missing feature. I would classify it as a bug. But it’s not like ISP routers get firmware updates :)

Comment: Putting the printer on a computer will solve the problem without need for help from the ISP.

Comment: But that would require the computer to be on 24/7 right? That wouldn't be ideal, also since I print quite infrequently, so its not worth the hassle. My problem should be very widespread, since I am not doing anything special, but I don't find any other reports of the problem online. Very weird. Anyways, I don't think anything more can be done. Should I accept your answer or not, since my question was not resolved? I don't know the exact rules.

Comment: There are no rules, it's up to you. You don't have enough reputation to upvote, so your only decision is to accept or not. Most people accept if they feel that there is probably not a better answer, but there are no rules.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the help! Back to using the printer with wires I guess.